# HW configuration for RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I need to run test automation scripts in a closed subnetwork, where only old Hardware is available.
Which is the minimum hw configuration (CPU, RAM, Disk size) needed to install and run robotframework ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any computer that can run a browser can probably run robot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.